# How to remove leaf member values?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dimension

I have a dimension hierarchy that is related to multiple fact tables with different granularities. In the case of one fact table, it relates to the middle level of a three level hierarchy.

When you drill down that dimension, I would prefer to have values at that granularity and nothing if you drill down further. The default behaviour seems to be just duplicating the parent total for each of the leaf members.

I thought there was a property to control this but for the life of me I can't find it now.

Comment: I think you are thinking of HidememberIF, but that really only works on Parent-child hierarchies rather than any hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In the cube-designer there is a tab "dimension usage" where you can set IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions for each measure group. When you set **IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions to False** for the measure group with the values you meant, the result should show null for levels below the granularity level.